# dependent or independent t test for two group

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, t-test

I have a loan data set. and i want to test whether the mean of variable "inquiries in the last 6 month" of the default group is different from the mean of the whole population (which include the default group, non default group). Can I use dependent t test?

And the same data set. if i test whether the mean of default group is different from mean of non default group. can I use the independent t test?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

First, as the other answer pointed out, if you have the entire population, the whole idea of inference becomes tricky.  I think, though, that you might mean "entire sample".

Your first question should probably be abandoned but if you insist on asking it, then I think the only way is some sort of permutation test.  Standard statistical tests won't allow you to answer it.

For your second question, if "inquiries" is a count variable (which seems likely) and if it has a skewed distribution (which also seems likely) then I would use a count regression model rather than a t-test. Welch's t-test allows for unequal variances but assumes normality - that is unlikely here.

As for a dependent test - no, there is nothing in your question that suggests that a dependent test would be appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Do the latter with a Welch t test.

I have never heard of a test comparing a subgroup of your data with the whole group that contains the subgroup. I'm not saying it's impossible, but at the very least highly unorthodox and it wouldn't allow you to benefit from the increased power of a paired test either so there is no reason to do it.

Also, when you do a t test you are implicitly saying you want to infer knowledge about the population by analyzing  a sample of that population. However, if your dataset contains the entire population, you don't need to do inference. All you would need to do is a census: just count the means and compare them to see if they are different.

Comment: I would still not treat it as an exogenous value if you have derived it from the same data set you are doing the test on though